# How to echo %random% instead of a random number in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How to echo %random instead of a random number.
I'm makeing a benchmarking/virus batch that pushes any pc to the max. I want it to write a program in a loop and run it in al loop. that file it writes I want to run in a loop. The Problem is is that I cant echo a variable as %variable%...

Here is the program I am trying to make:

```
@echo off
:start
set rn=%random%
cd %userprofile%
goto createcopy
:runnew
start %rn%
goto start
:createcopy
echo "echo @echo off >>%rn%.bat".bat
echo "echo :start >>%rn%.bat"%rn%.bat
echo "echo set rn= >>%rn%.bat"%rn%.bat
echo "echo cd %userprofile% >>%rn%.bat"%rn%.bat
echo "echo start %rn%>>%rn%.bat">>%rn%.bat
pause
goto runnew
```

Please help, and if you do thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the literal string `%Random%` by a batch file, you need to escape the `%` signs by doubling them, so the following accomplishes that:

```
rem This prints `%Random%` to the console:
echo %%Random%%
```

To do the same in command prompt directly, use the following command line:

```
rem This prints `%Random%` to the console:
echo ^%Random^%
```

---

To output special characters like `<`, `>`, `|`, `&`, `(`, `)` and `^`, which are not enclosed within a pair of `""`, escape them by preceding a `^` sign like in the following example:

```
rem This prints `<Tag>` to the console:
echo ^<Tag^>
```

This works for both batch files and command prompt.